# Programmatically Add a packageSource to packageSources in Nuget.Config

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I am trying to use the library NuGet.Configuration from NuGet to programmatically add a packageSource to my nuget.config.  (I can't use nuget.exe in AWS CodeBuild, at least without a ton of heavy lifting).

I can't make heads or tails of the NuGet.Configuration classes and how to operate them.

Essentially what I want to do is:

1. Load a NuGet.Config file
2. Add a package source
3. Add a packageSourceCredentials
4. Save it back to disk.

I can't find any examples out there.  Advise?

Answer (score 0):

No time to "dress this up" but essentially it is this:

```
                var setting = Settings.LoadSpecificSettings(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "NuGet.Config");

            // get sources 
            var packageSourceProvider = new PackageSourceProvider(setting);

            var packageSource = new PackageSource(repo.RepositoryEndpoint, "my-repo")
            {
                Credentials = new PackageSourceCredential("my-repo", "aws", authorizationTokenAsync.AuthorizationToken, true, string.Empty)
            };

            packageSourceProvider.AddPackageSource(packageSource);

            setting.SaveToDisk();
```